# Different output for different file extension -PHP

Tags: php, if-statement, file-extension

I want to give different output for different files extension - doc & docx.
This is my code

```
//get file extension

$filename = $row['uploadm_name'];
$path = $filename;
$ext = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

if($ext='doc') 
{
   include ('doc.php');
}
else if($ext='docx') 
{
   include ('docx.php');
}
```

It works when I open the doc extension file. However, when I open the docx extension file it give the output of doc extension file. And when I place the docx on the first if-else statement, the doc extension file will give the output docx file.

I thought that doc & docx are two different extension. But why does it looks like it is reading it as the same extension. Or am I doing it wrong? Please help me. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You require `==` in your if condition.

Try this :

```
if($ext=='doc') 
{
   include ('doc.php');
}
else if($ext=='docx') 
{
   include ('docx.php');
}
```

Comment: Got it. Thank you sir!

Answer (score 1):

`=` is assigment operator and `==` is comparision operator:

so in your case correct code will be

```
if($ext=='doc') 
{
   include ('doc.php');
}
else if($ext=='docx') 
{
   include ('docx.php');
}
```

for more detail have a look at PHP Operators: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.php